# Decorator on class makes class NoneType when importing

Tags: python, class, import, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to understand why a decorator on my class modifies the class in such way that it appears to be 'NoneType' when trying to import the class from another script.

In **`my_class.py`** I have:

```
my_dict = dict()

def register(cls):
    name = cls.__name__
    my_dict[name] = cls

@register  # will be commented
class MyClass:
    def my_method(self):
        print("running class method")

print("my_dict: ", my_dict)
```

In another module **`my_main.py`** I import the class like

```
from my_class import MyClass

print(type(MyClass))
print(MyClass.my_method)
```

If I run it with `$ python3 my_main.py` I get the following output:

```
my_dict:  {'MyClass': <class 'my_class.MyClass'>}
<class 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_main.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(MyClass.my_method)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'my_method'
```

By commenting the `@register` line in `my_class.py` the `my_main.py` runs without error and outputs:

```
my_dict:  {}
<class 'type'>
<function MyClass.my_method at 0x7ff06f254f28>
```

..but obviously `my_dict` is no longer filled. Is there a way of registering `my_class` with the given decorator AND accessing the attributes of the class after importing it in another script?

Comment: Your decorator does not return your class (but None implicitly). Add a `return cls` to your register function

Comment: oh, of course... now it makes sense - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A decorator is no more than just a normal function.

I don't want to describe a lot about how to write a decorator rightly. But at least, you should let your decorator return a `class`.

That is similar when you write a decorator for a function. Decorator should at least return a function.

For example:

```
def decorator(method):
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Hi")
        return method(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

When you use this decorator to decorate a function, you are actually pass that function to decorator: `new_function = decorator(original_function)`.

Which means `new_function` is wrapped by `wrapper`. That is how decorator works. When you execute decorated function, it actually execute the `wrapper`:

```
print("Hi")
return method(*args, **kwargs)  # pass all args to original function and return its return value.
```

In your code, your decorator just returns `None`.